# Use nc on TCP port tell is a service is up?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, centos

Can I use the following trick on any TCP port to wait for a service to come up?

```
while true; do
    nc -i 1 10.10.10.10 3306 >/dev/null && break
done
```

Comment: Yes. Though you may want to add a counter to exit after a certain amount of tries to avoid it running forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop waits for the connection to become available, but also for the successful connection to be closed by the server (which may never happen). Here's an alternative version that just waits until the port is open:

```
until nc -z 10.10.10.10 3306
do
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: I assume that you use Ubuntu because of `-z`. Would that be `-l` `Listen for connections rather than connecting to a remote machine`?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes `-z` is the option in both OpenBSD netcat and traditional (hobbit) netcat to scan for listening daemons without sending data, i.e. disconnect immediately and return status.